# Getting error when using printf in c++, LNK1104 exe file could not be opened

Tags: c++, visual-studio, linker-errors

Started a c++ project in Visual Studio, and the only thing I have written so far is a Hello world program. However, if I switch from using `std::cout` to `printf()`, I get a LNK1104 error saying that the exe file could not be opened.

**This will compile and run:**

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout<< "Hello World";
    return 0;
}
```

**This wont:**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("hello World\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Functions like `scanf` work just fine though.

Comment: Please include the error message in the question. "the exe file could not be opened." is an errror you get long after compiling and linking and it just tells you that something went wrong and there is no executable. The actual error is something else

Comment: Please copy&paste the exact error message. If the linker cannot open the .exe file, maybe the program is still running?

Comment: Besides, I would change the header to the appropriate c++ header, #include <cstdio>

Comment: Build on VisualStudio 2019 working fine.

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 That is wrong. It happens during linking when the linker can't open the target file for writing. Often because it's an executable still running.

Comment: `#include <stdio.h>` is the C header file for using C.  `#include <cstdio>` is the C++ header for using C++, with which you can access `std::printf`.

Answer (score 1):

> This error is reported when the linker fails to open a file, either for reading or for writing.

There are many different issues that can report this error, see [Linker Tools Error LNK1104](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/tool-errors/linker-tools-error-lnk1104?view=vs-2019)

My guess would be:

> your program is already running or is loaded in the debugger.

If that's the case you can try yo kill the process int task manager, doing it will assert if that is the issue.

If you include the verbatim error it can help narrow the field.